# Calculation of cut height/depth of a cut in Sequent Calculus

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, proof-theory, sequent-calculus

I am having trouble understanding the calculation of an idea, which is called 'cut height' in Negri and von Plato's *Structural Proof Theory* (SPT), and 'depth of a cut' in Troelstra and Schwichtenberg's *Basic Proof Theory* (BPT).

Cut height, according to SPT, is as follows:
[image]

And depth of a cut as defined in BPT:
[image]
[image]

As far as I understand, 'height' in SPT means the same thing as 'depth' in BPT. If we compare the cut height formulation to the (*) property, they also seem to be saying the same thing.

---

But looking at the example below from BPT, I would have expected that for the cut in the 2nd sequent calculus below to have a cut height/depth of $d_{01}+(d_{00}+d_{10})+1$. But BPT puts it as $\max(d_{00},d_{01})+1+d_{10}+1$.

So why the $\max(d_{00},d_{01})$? (And what is all the transformation he is doing there?) Am I mistaken in thinking that both SPT and BPT are talking about the same thing?

[image]

---

EDIT: Adding BPT's definition of depth below
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't have BPT with me, but it seems to me that in BPT depth refers to a notion of size for a whole derivation, whereas the cut height in SPT refers to a notion of size for an instance of the cur rule in a derivation. Anyway, in BPT, 4.1.4 is not a definition of depth, it just fixes some notations. Could you provide the definition of depth in BPT?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Please refer to the edit I added to the bottom of the question; this is the only time where a definition of depth has been given, but it doesn't seem like BPT's def of depth directly refers to that of a derivation, but of other things (such as formulas)

Comment: First, the definition of depth of a tree says it is the length of the longest branch. Second, the  depth $\max(d_{00}, d_{01}) + d_{10} +1$ refers to the first derivation, before the transformation, not the second. (Do you see how that is the length of the longest branch?) It's perhaps true that BPT isn't clear here, but terms, formulas, and derivations are all trees.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen In BPT, it seems to me that whatever is *ed, it is always referring to the transformed derivation...so I don't understand why it is referring to the 1st (before being transformed) derivation. Truth be told, nothing about that depth calculation makes sense to me...especially the max() bit.

Comment: @DanielMak Sorry, made a mistake. The equation $d^* = \max(d_{01}, \max(d_{00},d_{10}) + 1) + 1$ refers to the depth of the second tree. The RHS of the inequality they are trying to establish $d^* \le (\max(d_{00}, d_{01}) + 1) + (d_{10}+1)$ refers to the sum of the depths of the two branches of the first tree, as per inequality (*). So what you wrote down was a quantity in reference to the first tree, but I was wrong to say it was the length of the longest branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of *cut-height* in SPT (p. 35) is the same as the definition of *level* of a cut in BPT (p. 93).

Note that the notion cut-height in SPT refers to a size of an occurrence the cut rule in a derivation; whereas, in BPT, the notion of *depth* refers to a size of a *whole* derivation. Its definition in BPT is given in general as the depth of a tree, see p. 9. 
Since derivations are special cases of trees (whose nodes are sequents), this provides also a definition of *depth* of a derivation $\mathcal{D}$: it is the *greatest* number of successive applications of non-$0$-ary rules in a *branch* of $\mathcal{D}$ (so, it coincides with the definition of *height* of $\mathcal{D}$ in SPT, p. 30).

Even in the case of the proof of Theorem 4.1.5 in BPT (what you are interested in), the notions of depth of a derivation and cut-height of a cut do not coincide, even if you are considering only derivations whose last rule is a cut and you compare the depth of such derivations with the cut-height of such a (last) cut.
Indeed, the cut-height of a cut $c$ is (in the terminology of BPT) the *sum* of the depths of the two derivations that are premises $c$, not their maximum (or their maximum plus $1$).

Concretely, concerning your case 3a in the proof of Theorem 4.1.5 in BPT, if $\mathcal{D}^*$ is the derivation
\begin{align}
 \dfrac{\overset{\mathcal{D}_{01}}{\Gamma \Rightarrow \Delta, D_1} \qquad
   \dfrac{\overset{\mathcal{D}_{00}[D_1 \Rightarrow]}{\Gamma \Rightarrow \Delta, D_0} \qquad 
\overset{\mathcal{D}_{10}}{D_0, D_1, \Gamma \Rightarrow \Delta}}
   {D_1, \Gamma \Rightarrow \Delta}\text{cut}_\text{cs}
 }{\Gamma \Rightarrow \Delta}\text{cut}_\text{cs}
\end{align}
then the depth of $\mathcal{D}^*$ is $d^* = \max ({d_{01}}, \max (d_{00}, d_{10}) + 1) + 1$, as correctly stated on p. 97.